# arcgis flex widget close a window and open another window with datagrid

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, widget

I uses Arcgis api for flex 3.6 and adobe flash builder 4.6. I want to develop a widget use a window (say window 1) to allow user to input searching criteria, after click "Ok", window 1 should close and another window (say window 2) should open, in window 2 display the searching results (based on window 1 user input searching criteria) in a datagrid. I wonder whether this possible to be?

Comment: look at this link above, it should help i hope ... http://web.zone.ee/bespiva/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close and Open Widget
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2421&t=277136

to share data in between widgets you can use 
[Creating a local SharedObject](https://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/1/lsos/lsos3.html)